# Send script results to other computer on local network

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am running a script every 30 seconds (on a RaspberryPi) to get the temperature (DS18B20). I want to send the temperature data to another computer on my network. I tried having the temperature data written to an XML file and the file served by SimpleHTTPServer then the remote computer parse the XML file. This all worked well but if the XML file is being written at the same time it is trying to be parsed the parsing script fails.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I could accomplish what I am looking for?

Comment: Why can't you just use sockets?

Answer (score 0):

A few quick ideas:

1. Write the temperature sensor data to a [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) DB/file, then add a route to SimpleHTTPServer that reads the data. Benefits being you can always just easily port the entire database by reading the SQLite file and avoiding the lock-issues you've mentioned.
2. Simple JSON strings being written to [Redis](http://redis.io/) and read by SimpleHTTPServer by endpoint as described above.
3. Swap SimpleHTTPServer for [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).

I would start with option #1, personally, as I think it has least amount of overhead and gels with your existing setup.

Comment: What if my script tries to read the SQLite DB/file when the file is being updated? Will I not run into the same problem?

Comment: The short answer is no, you're safe, it's guaranteed by [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) compliance. You can read about how SQLite does it in more detail [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) if you're interested.